# Dynamic CSS with AnguarJS / Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need set a custom style of dynamics div.
Div are conforms to the balise :

```
<div class="row">
    <div id={{'letter'+$index}} ng-style="{{theStyle}}" class="col" 
         ng-repeat="letter in letters track by $index">{{letter}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The color of each letter must be defined in function of a level and by the value of the index that are declared in an array. I have three levels (low, medium, high), so the low-style, the medium-style and the high-style. The array can be for example: ['color': 'white', 'border-color': 'blue', ..., 'color': 'white', 'border-color': 'red']. For each letter there are an element of the array.

Could you suggest a smart solution for this case ?

Thanks

EDIT: The variables used in the controller are:

```
var word = getWord(objectWord, getLanguage());
$scope.letters = word.split('');
$scope.level = getLevelCSS(getLevel());
var arrStyles = getStyles(letters.length);
```

Comment: Can you add arrays/object you are working with? What you posted is not valid. Post `letters` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your ng-style a directive function like this

```
<div ng-style="changetheColor(style-level, colorinfo)" colordirective></div>
```

And the directive would look smth like this

```
.directive('colordirective', function (Ls) {
         return function (scope, element, attr) {

             scope.changetheColor = function (level, color) {
                   if(level == 'medium'){

                    return color;

                    }else if(level == 'high'){

                        return color;

                    }
        }
    }

})
```

If u want u can pass the Level and the style info from the array and return it in the directive

Comment: Could you be more specific about ? Thanks

Comment: well the changetheColor function is called for every element which has "colordirective" so when u for example ng-repeat over some array every element gets the color depending on the "style-level" (medium - high....)

Comment: you said every letter has an array element so basicly every letter would get a different color depending on the level in my example medium would be green and high would be red

Comment: I need pass the level info and the array of styles. Both parameters are important for me

Comment: i just changed my answer so u need to pass the level and the colorinfo to the directive function and there u just return the colorinfo depending on the style-level